# Retrieving key from value in hashtable in Java

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashtable

I am a new bie to the world of collections but still, In my below class I have hashtable as I have to choose hashtable and I want to retrieve the key basis on the value , below is my class..

```
public class KeyFromValueExample
 {
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
        table.put("Sony", "Bravia");
        table.put("Samsung", "Galaxy");
        table.put("Nokia", "Lumia");
System.out.println("does hash table has Lumia as value : " + table.containsValue("Lumia"));
        System.out.println("does hash table Lumia as key : " + table.containsKey("Lumia"));

        //finding key corresponding to value in hashtable - one to one mapping
        String key= null;
        String value="Lumia";
        for(Map.Entry entry: table.entrySet()){
            if(value.equals(entry.getValue())){
                key = entry.getKey();
                break; //breaking because its one to one map
            }
        }
        System.out.println("got key from value in hashtable key:  "+ key +" value: " + value);

//finding key corresponding to value in hashtable - one to many mapping
        table.put("HTC", "Lumia");
        Set keys = new HashSet();

        for(Map.Entry entry: table.entrySet()){
            if(value.equals(entry.getValue())){
                keys.add(entry.getKey()); //no break, looping entire hashtable
            }
        }
        System.out.println("keys : " + keys +" corresponding to value in hash table:  "+ value);
```

Output :-

```
does hash table has Lumia as value : true
does hash table has Lumia as key : false
got key from value in hashtable key:  Nokia value: Lumia
keys : [Nokia, HTC] corresponding to value in hash talbe:  Lumia
```

Now please advis is there any other better way to achieve the same thing, Please advise if other better alternatives are there.

Answer (score 2):

That looks pretty obvious what it's doing to me.  I'm not sure there's a more efficient way of doing it, but perhaps if you need to look up values to find the keys quite regularly, then the type of map you are using is wrong.  I would suggest you turn the values into keys and make a `Map<String, Set<String>>` instead

Answer (score 1):

If your map has both unique keys and values, consider using BiMap from Guava collections -> http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

With that library, you can just use simple `containsKey` and `containsValue` tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot could you please convert and post my code in to googlebitMap one that will make understanding more clear,Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2094103: as Alexander Pogrebnyak stated, a `BiMap` only works for unique keys and unique values. You have duplicates in your values...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is what you want, but why don't you reverse your key and values? So, you can use

```
table.put("Lumia", new List<String>("HTC", "Nokia"));
```

something like that if above is legal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there  a way to find the key of a particular value in HashTable without iterator??
like String getvalue(key); ??

for(Map.Entry entry: table.entrySet()){
            if(value.equals(entry.getValue())){
                keys.add(entry.getKey()); //no break, looping entire hashtable
            }
        }
```